# Changing certain letters in a column's cell values to a formula

Tags: excel

Consider a cell with imported value `27.873 M` in which `M` stands for million. It’s actually lots of them and it isn’t possible to change them manually.

Are there any macros or VBAs to trace letter `M` in them, remove it and then multiply the cell’s value by `1,000,000` so that the final value becomes `27,873,000`?

Comment: How many letters are we talking? M,K,...

Comment: What about search and replace? You can replace " M" by ".000.000", maybe a bit tuned with regular expressions to handle whitespace with differing length (if supported by Excel). If not and you need the power of regular expressions you can export the data to CSV and use an editor like Notepad++.

Comment: You can do this with a macro, but you should try to write one yourself and come back with specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the data "in-place", run this short macro:

```
Sub DataFixer()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Right(r.Value, 1) = "M" Then
            r.Value = CLng((Trim(Replace(r.Value, "M", "")))) * 1000000
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula in an empty column:

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2))*CHOOSE(MATCH(RIGHT(A2,1),{"M","K"},0),10^6,10^3)
```

[image]

Just add to the letter in the `{}` and add the value by which we multiply the number.

---

Edit

If it is only in groups of 10^3 then you can simplify the formula to:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1))*10^(MATCH(RIGHT(A1,1),{"K","M","B"},0)*3)
```